# How can I make pandas treat the start of the next business day as the next time after the previous business day?

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I have financial trade data (timestamped with the trade time, so there are duplicate times and the datetimes are irregularly spaced).  Basically I have just a datetime column and a price column in a pandas dataframe, and I've calculated returns, but I want to linearly interpolate the data so that I can get an estimate of prices every second, minute, day, etc...

It seems the best way to do this is treat the beginning of a Tuesday as occurring just after the end of Monday, so essentially modding out by the time between days.  Does pandas provide an easy way to do this?  I've searched the documentation and found BDay, but that doesn't seem to do what I want.

Edit:  Here's a sample of my code:

```
df = read_csv(filePath,usecols=[0,4]) #column 0 is date_time and column 4 is price
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time,format = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f') 

def get_returns(df):
    return np.log(df.Price.shift(1) / df.Price)
```

But my issue is that this is trade data, so that I have every trade that occurs for a given stock over some time period, trading happens only during a trading day (9:30 am - 4 pm), and the data is timestamped.  I can take the price that every trade happens at and make a price series, but when I calculate kurtosis and other stylized facts, I'm getting very strange results because these sorts of statistics are usually run on evenly spaced time series data.

What I started to do was write code to interpolate my data linearly so that I could get the price every 10 seconds, minute, 10 minutes, hour, day, etc.  However, with business days, weekends, holidays, and all the time where trading can't happen, I want to make python think that the only time which exists is during a business day, so that my real world times still match up with the correct date times, but not such that I need a price stamp for all the times when trading is closed.

```
def lin_int_tseries(series, timeChange):
    tDelta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=timeChange)
    data_times = series['date_time']
    new_series = []
    sample_times = []
    sample_times.append(data_times[0])
    while max(sample_times) < max(data_times):
        sample_times.append(sample_times[-1] + tDelta)
    for position,time in enumerate(sample_times):
        try: 
            ind = data_times.index(time)
            new_series.append(series[ind])
        except:
            t_next = getnextTime(time,data_times) #get next largest timestamp in data
            t_prev = getprevTime(time,data_times) #get next smallest timestamp in data
            ind_next = data_times.index(t_next) #index of next largest timestamp
            ind_prev = data_times.index(t_prev) #index of next smallest timestamp
            p_next = series[ind_next][1] #price at next timestamp
            p_prev = series[ind_prev][1] #price a prev timestamp
            omega = (float(time) - t_prev)/(t_next - t_prev) #linear interpolation
            p_interp = (1 - omega)*p_prev + omega*p_next
        new_series.append([time,p_interp])
    return new_series
```

Sorry if it's still unclear.  I just want to find some way to stitch the end of one trading day to the beginning of the next trading day, while not losing the actual datetime information.

Comment: Can you give an example DataFrame (input and output) / code sample, it's hard to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm just trying to run some basic statistics on my data (and eventually do some more sophisticated stuff with fourier transforms and distribution comparisons), but the resolution is too high to fit most of the so called "stylized facts".

With code I've posted, the linear interpolation will create timeChange increments with associated prices even while exchanges are closed (nights and weekends), which will affect my results significantly.

Comment: You should use pandas resample:

df=df.resample("D")

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas resample:

```
df=df.resample("D")
```